# A buffer overflow only returning seg fault and not jumping to the address of a function

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

So I'm trying to apply buffer overflow on this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void hello()
{
        printf("WELCOME TO THE SYSTEM");
}

int main(){
        char passwd[10];
        printf("ENTER THE PASSWORD: ");
        scanf("%s", passwd);
        if (strcmp(passwd,"pass")==0)
                hello();
        else
                printf("WRONG PASSWORD");
}
```

I'm going to overflow the buffer passwd with the addresss of the function hello and I'm expecting to see "WELCOME TO THE SYSTEM" but all I get is a Segmentation fault. I used gdb for further investigation,

```
(gdb) print &hello
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x555555555159 <hello>
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/reader/server
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
ENTER THE PASSWORD: aaaaaaaaa\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x59\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55\x55

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555551eb in main () at server.c:17
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
```

The address of the hello function didn't change after execution. Here are the info registers

```
rax            0x0                 0
rbx            0x7fffffffe188      140737488347528
rcx            0x0                 0
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x415020474e4f5257  4706297101230756439
rdi            0x7fffffffde80      140737488346752
rbp            0x5c3135785c393578  0x5c3135785c393578
rsp            0x7fffffffe078      0x7fffffffe078
r8             0xffff              65535
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x7ffff7f4d210      140737353404944
r11            0x7ffff7f4c800      140737353402368
r12            0x0                 0
r13            0x7fffffffe198      140737488347544
r14            0x555555557dd8      93824992247256
r15            0x7ffff7ffd000      140737354125312
rip            0x5555555551eb      0x5555555551eb <main+119>
eflags         0x10202             [ IF RF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```

as you can see rbp got overwriten.

Comment: Standard input does not translate character escape codes into characters, and neither does standard input invoked through gdb. You need to send the data as binary, not a textual representation of binary. Your input `\x59` is going to literally be those four characters, not a single byte with the value 0x59. Since you are using a debugger, you ought to attempt some basic investigation, which would result in you realizing this.

Comment: @paddy should I convert the function address into binary and then reverse it?

Comment: That's a weird question from someone who is performing a buffer overflow attack. Do you understand how machine code is actually represented on the target system?

Comment: @paddy I don't think I do.

Comment: Your system is likely using little-endian. Most systems are, nowadays. Forget about the actual attack for now and just focus on figuring out what the heck you're even doing. You can determine byte order experimentally by writing some data into memory and then reading back the value to see if it's what you expect. If you can't even do that, you face a serious uphill struggle writing code exploits. Try learning some C and assembly first.

Comment: Though from the other end of the spectrum you are to be commended for using `gdb` and the other tools you have to try and investigate your problem. All are part of the learning process. Nobody starts out knowing how to do this stuff. You start with an empty slate and slowly add learning and experience to get to the point you know what it is you are doing and what you need to accomplish. @paddy advice is sound. If you are struggling with the basic code of the exploit, visit [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @paddy Can I just ask why the RIP register wasn't set to string I inputted? is it because the string wasn't a valid memory address?

Comment: Please read my very first comment. Carefully. Until you understand it.